# JTextField caret not showing properly

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

I have a JTextField in a JFrame. The caret blinks between a normal looking caret and a half drawn caret.
[image: Screen Shot]

The caret only shows at the top and bottom. I have tried using custom carets but they all only show part of the graphic. The bug is the same for the password field too. I don't know if it's relevant but I'm on a mac and I don't own a windows machine to test if the bug occurs on windows as well.
Here is an MCVE of my window (as short as I could make it):

```
public class Login1 extends JFrame implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel pnl_mainPanel;
private JButton btn_login_main, btn_newAccount, btn_seeAccounts, btn_login_login, btn_cancel_login, btn_next, btn_cancel_new;
private JTextField tf_username_login, tf_username_new;
private JPasswordField pf_password, pf_password_new, pf_password_confirm;
private JLabel lbl_username_login, lbl_password_login, lbl_username_new, lbl_password_new, lbl_password_confirm;

private static final String TITLE = "Login";
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
private final Dimension WINDOW_DIM = new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

public Login1() {
    super(TITLE);
    setSize(WINDOW_DIM);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buildPanel();
    add(pnl_mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}

private void buildPanel() {
    pnl_mainPanel = new JPanel();
    btn_login_main = new JButton("Login");
    btn_newAccount = new JButton("New Account");
    btn_seeAccounts = new JButton("ℹ");

    // login page
    btn_login_login = new JButton("Login");
    btn_cancel_login = new JButton("Cancel");
    tf_username_login = new JTextField();
    pf_password = new JPasswordField();
    lbl_username_login = new JLabel("Username:");
    lbl_password_login = new JLabel("Password:");

    // new account page
    btn_next = new JButton("Next");
    btn_cancel_new = new JButton("Cancel");
    tf_username_new = new JTextField();
    pf_password_new = new JPasswordField();
    pf_password_confirm = new JPasswordField();
    lbl_username_new = new JLabel("Username:");
    lbl_password_new = new JLabel("Password:");
    lbl_password_confirm = new JLabel("<html>Confirm<br>Password:</html>");

    pnl_mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_login_main);
    pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_newAccount);
    pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_seeAccounts);

    btn_login_login.setSize(75, 30);
    btn_login_login.setLocation(new Point(310, 175));
    btn_cancel_login.setSize(75, 30);
    btn_cancel_login.setLocation(new Point(310, 215));
    tf_username_login.setSize(200, 25);
    tf_username_login.setLocation(new Point(100, 178));
    pf_password.setSize(200, 25);
    pf_password.setLocation(new Point(100, 218));
    lbl_username_login.setSize(100, 25);
    lbl_username_login.setLocation(new Point(15, 178));
    lbl_password_login.setSize(100, 25);
    lbl_password_login.setLocation(new Point(15, 218));

    btn_next.setSize(75, 30);
    btn_next.setLocation(new Point(310, 160));
    btn_cancel_new.setSize(75, 30);
    btn_cancel_new.setLocation(new Point(310, 200));
    tf_username_new.setSize(200, 25);
    tf_username_new.setLocation(new Point(100, 163));
    pf_password_new.setSize(200, 25);
    pf_password_new.setLocation(new Point(100, 203));
    pf_password_confirm.setSize(200, 25);
    pf_password_confirm.setLocation(new Point(100, 243));
    lbl_username_new.setSize(100, 25);
    lbl_username_new.setLocation(new Point(15, 163));
    lbl_password_new.setSize(100, 25);
    lbl_password_new.setLocation(new Point(15, 203));
    lbl_password_confirm.setSize(100, 30);
    lbl_password_confirm.setLocation(new Point(15, 238));

    btn_login_main.setSize(163, 100);
    btn_login_main.setLocation(new Point(25, 150));
    btn_newAccount.setSize(162, 100);
    btn_newAccount.setLocation(new Point(213, 150));
    btn_seeAccounts.setSize(20, 20);
    btn_seeAccounts.setLocation(new Point(375, 255));

    btn_login_main.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_login_main);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_newAccount);

            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_next);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_cancel_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(tf_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(pf_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(pf_password_confirm);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_password_confirm);

            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_login_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_cancel_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(tf_username_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(pf_password);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(lbl_username_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(lbl_password_login);
            repaint();
            tf_username_login.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    btn_cancel_login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_login_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(tf_username_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(pf_password);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_cancel_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_username_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_password_login);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_login_main);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_newAccount);
            repaint();
        }
    });
    btn_newAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_login_main);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_newAccount);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_next);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_cancel_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(tf_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(pf_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(pf_password_confirm);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(lbl_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(lbl_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(lbl_password_confirm);
            repaint();
            tf_username_new.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    btn_cancel_new.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_next);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(btn_cancel_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(tf_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(pf_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(pf_password_confirm);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_username_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_password_new);
            pnl_mainPanel.remove(lbl_password_confirm);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_login_main);
            pnl_mainPanel.add(btn_newAccount);
            repaint();
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Login1 l = new Login1();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information. The best thing you can do is create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - a simplified version of your program that shows the problem (read details in the link). Put the simplified code as an edit to your question, so we can copy and run it and see the problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic This comes from a large class for a login window. Is this a common error? I added the actionlistener for the button that shows the textfield

Comment: That's not an MCVE. The idea is to **write a new program** that is *small*, but that we can compile and run ourselves to see your problem. It takes time, yes, but since it's not obvious where the source of the problem is, it requires a complete program, so you have to make a new, small one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I added an mcve

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't experience the deformed cursor when I run your code sample. Perhaps toggle your cursor mode from *overtype* to *insert* using the [insert (INS) key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) and see how that affects its appearance.

Comment: @gknicker Thanks for the response. There's no insert key on a macbook pro, nor a keystroke that works

Comment: A bit irrelevant to the problem, but look into `CardLayout`. In your listeners, it seems as if you remove things from the panel, preparing it for new components (taking out login components to add in chat components or something). Instead, have 2 panels and switch between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this happens on my Mac, and does not happen on my Linux.

It can be easily solved by changing the height of the field to at least 28.

```
tf_username_login.setSize(200, 28);
```

My guess is that Mac OS X cannot create a field whose height is less than 28 pixels (though this may be a question of font choice etc., I haven't tested it that far). For some reason, it draws the full caret at full height (28 pixels), but erases it at the user indicated size (25) which causes the phenomenon you have noticed.

Comment: I thought Swing was platform independent

Comment: There is no such thing as platform independent when it comes to GUI. Eventually, the code gets translated into system-dependent calls.

Comment: Better to avoid `setSize()`, etc.; instead, use a layout and `pack()` the enclosing `Window`.

Comment: @trashgod this is just a small project for myself. I don't plan on publishing it. I understand how layouts work but I just went with an absolute layout for this one and set resizable to false